# initially show place holder on md-datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-material

I need to show only the placeholder text on md-datepicker before selecting a date. But when I send a null value to md-datepickeer it default show the current date.

This is my angularjs controller code line to pass null date

```js
appCtrl.myDate = null;
```

This is my html code.

```html
 <md-datepicker-custom name="dateField" 
                     ng-model="appCtrl.myDate" 
                     md-placeholder="Enter time" >
                     </md-datepicker-custom>
```

It show current date. I need to get clear field and it should show placeholder text.

[image: screen shot example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove formatDate function from config, then placeholder is working.

Here is the snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngMaterial']);

app.config(function($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
  $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = formatDate;

  function formatDate(date) {
    return date ? moment(date).format('L') : '';
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.8/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <md-datepicker name="terminationDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" ng-model="vm.terminationDate">
  </md-datepicker>


  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<md-datepicker
  name="terminationDate"
  md-placeholder="Enter date"
  ng-model="vm.terminationDate">
</md-datepicker>
```

Please refer this : http://plnkr.co/edit/O5ePYKyo1ILlheMz8KdO?p=preview 
It may help you.